# Does firebase exports save the photos and images in your database within the export itself?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a firebase database and exported it using a schedule according to the following manual.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#gcp-console

Inside the main function I have `collectionIds: []` to store everything. Once I ran the backup, I noticed that my database which was calculated to be `2.02 MiB` was backed up to a folder with size `96.21 KiB`. This makes me wonder if the export actually backed up photos or if the compression is really that good. Is there a way to know for sure if the photos are contained? Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting photos to be backed up? Are you actually storing the binary data of a photo in your document fields?

Comment: Yes, I assumed by specifying the document field as an empty field, photos are included.

Comment: So you are, in fact, storing binary photo data as a field in a document, and not just a URL to a file?  Please be clear.

Comment: sorry, I think perhaps I lack understanding of how firebase works. I just went into my bucket and saw that I have images saved as "application/octet-stream
". I am confused what it means to store the binary data in my document fields. Currently in my app I reference these photos with a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore exports will contain all data in all documents with all fields present.  The export will **not** attempt to crawl any URLs in those fields, or try to get any other external data to save as well.  You will have to handle external data separately.

There is almost certainly no data missing in the export.  The difference in size between your database as reported in Firestore, and the size reported in Cloud Storage could be attributed to the fact that size in Firestore includes all of the indexes it builds that are required for serving queries efficiently.  Those indexes do not need to be exported.  They can be rebuilt after import.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, my images within the firestore bucket are considered documents?

Comment: No, Cloud Storage is a completely different product.